# How to custom order/sort objects in a list

Tags: java, sorting

I have a list of objects which I want to order/sort in a specific order.

I have a list of Promotion objects. Each promotion will have a description. Two out of all the promotions will have description set to "premium" and "ordinary"

I want to order/sort the list such that promotion with description "premium" should always be at the end of the list and promotion with description "ordinary" show always be at list.size - 1 position. Example below

> [{description=...}, {description=...}, ..... {description=ordinary},
>   {description=premium}]

I tried using Collections.sort to sort the objects by passing a custom Comparator like below

```
public int compare(Promotion p1, Promotion p2) {
        if(p1.getDescription().equals("ordinary")) {
    return -size-1; // size is the size of the list passed as a constructor argument to the Comparator.
    }
if(p1.getDescription().equals("premium")) {
    return -size;
}
return 0;
}
```

I tried with the above code and I did not get the desired output while testing.

I later added another check in each of the if conditions to check to check description in p2 objects as well like below

```
p1.getDescription().equals("premium") || p2.getDescription().equals("premium")
```

What am I doing wrong here? Or am I using Collections.sort in wrong way? Can anyone please suggest/help me?

Comment: What happens if your list doesn't have a "premium" item?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The [Comparator](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Comparator.html) method [compare](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Comparator.html#compare-T-T-) takes two elements and returns a negative value if **x < y**, 0 if **x equals y** or a positive value if **x > y**.

In this case you can put the classes in an array sorted with priorities like this:

```
String classes[] = new String[]{"premimum", "ordinary", "less than ordinary"};
```

then you can compare with indices of the elements like this:

```
public int compare(Promotion p1, Promotion p2) {
Integer index1 = getIndexInsideClasses(p1.getDescription);
Integer index2 = getIndexInsideClasses(p2.getDescription);
       return index1.compareTo(index2);
   }
```

Comment: I would use a List instead of an array for `classes` and take advantage that `indexOf` returns -1 if the searched description is not on the List. So the List only needs to contain `"ordinary"` and `"premium"`. (Or just a switch inside `getIndexInsideClasses`)

Comment: A comparator doesn't necessarily return `-1` or `1`. The definition is "negative" or "positive". `-1` is as legal as `-5` (and has exactly the same meaning).

Answer (score 0):

Acording to the documentation of compare:

```
Compares its two arguments for order. Returns a negative integer, zero, or a positive integer as the first argument is less than, equal to, or greater than the second.
```

So say we want to sort a list of integers. We can create the following compare method:

```
        public int compare(Integer o1, Integer o2) {
            if(o1.intValue() < o2.intValue()) 
                return -1;
            if(o1.intValue() > o2.intValue()) 
                return 1;

            return 0;
        }
```

When the first value is smaller than the second, we return a negative value, when the first value is bigger than than the second, we return a positive value, when the two values are equal than we return 0.

So you can do something similar:

```
        public int compare(String o1, String o2) {
            if(o1.equals(o2))
                return 0; 
            if(o1.equals("ordinary") && o2.equals("premium")) 
                return 1;
            if(o1.equals("premium") && o2.equals("ordinary")) 
                return -1;

            return 0;
        }
```

When the values are similar, return 0. When the first value is "premium" we should return -1 and when the first is "ordinary" we return 1.

Regardless, it isn't really a good idea to use strings in this case to represnt description. That is because it can be confusing to use strings to represent usable data in your code, instead strings should be used for user interaction mostly. You should use something like an enumeration instead.

### EDIT

If the values might not be "ordinary" or "premium", than we could change the code to look like this:

```
public int compare(String o1, String o2) {
    if(o1.equals(o2))
        return 0; 
    if(o1.equals("ordinary") || o2.equals("premium")) 
        return 1;
    if(o1.equals("premium") || o2.equals("ordinary")) 
        return -1;

    return 0;
}
```

So this time, if o1 is "ordinary" we return 1 to move it to the end of the collection, if o2 is "ordinary" we return -1 to move it to the end. We do an opposite thing with "premium".

Comment: but what happens if one or both the Strings are not "ordinary" nor "premium"? quote from question: Two out of all the promotions will have description set to "premium" and "ordinary"

Comment: It is still possible to handle those cases. If we have other Strings we could add additional if conditions. When o1 is "ordinary" and o2 is neither "premium" nor "ordinary" we return -1. We can do something similar with "premium".

Comment: it sure is possible to handle those, but above code is not doing it  correctly (as asked). Actually the last snippet is breaking the Comparator, see [Javadoc](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Comparator.html#compare-T-T-): "The implementor must ensure that sgn(compare(x, y)) == -sgn(compare(y, x)) for all x and y." e.g. for `x="ordinary"` and `y="nothing"`

Comment: You are right, I've missed that before. It's fixed now, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Just optimizing [Alnours code](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45011588/85421) (his answer should stay the accepted one):

```
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.Collections;
import java.util.Comparator;
import java.util.List;

/** Note: this comparator imposes orderings that are inconsistent with equals. */
public class MyComparator implements Comparator<Promotion> {

    // any value not on the list will be considered less than the values on it
    // since indexOf returns -1 for these.
    private static final List<String> CLASSES = 
            Collections.unmodifiableList(Arrays.asList("ordinary", "premium"));

    @Override
    public int compare(Promotion p1, Promotion p2) {
        int i1 = CLASSES.indexOf(p1.getDescription());
        int i2 = CLASSES.indexOf(p2.getDescription());
        return Integer.compare(i1, i2);
    }
}
```

This will *move*  all promotions with the description given on `CLASSES` to the end ordering according the order given in `CLASSES`. All promotions whose description is not on `CLASSES` maintain their relative order.